# How get Timeindex, where Two Dataframes both have only NaNs in Row?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, indexing

I have two dataframes X and Y (both have a timeindex).
both have an intersection,but also indices which the other doesnt necessarily includes.

How to get the timeindex, where both **intersect** and boths **row is only-NaNs**?

reproducable:

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd
X = pd.DataFrame( {"a":[1,np.nan,3,4,5,np.nan,7,8,100,9,np.nan,np.nan,12,13,14,15],"b":[1,np.nan,3,4,5,6,7,8,101,9,np.nan,np.nan,12,13,np.nan,15]}, 
                    index =pd.DatetimeIndex(["2019-07-18 08:51:00", "2019-07-18 08:52:00","2019-07-18 08:53:00","2019-07-18 08:54:00","2019-07-18 08:55:00","2019-07-18 08:56:00","2019-07-18 08:57:00","2019-07-18 08:58:00","2019-07-18 08:58:30","2019-07-18 08:59:00","2019-07-18 09:00:00","2019-07-18 09:01:00","2019-07-18 09:02:00","2019-07-18 09:03:00","2019-07-18 09:04:00","2019-07-18 09:05:00" ]))
Y = pd.DataFrame({"c":[0,1,np.nan,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,np.nan,np.nan,12,13,14,15,16],"d":[0,1,np.nan,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,np.nan,np.nan,12,13,14,np.nan,16]}, 
                    index =pd.DatetimeIndex(["2019-07-18 08:50:00","2019-07-18 08:51:00", "2019-07-18 08:52:00","2019-07-18 08:53:00","2019-07-18 08:54:00","2019-07-18 08:55:00","2019-07-18 08:56:00","2019-07-18 08:57:00","2019-07-18 08:58:00","2019-07-18 08:59:00","2019-07-18 09:00:00","2019-07-18 09:01:00","2019-07-18 09:02:00","2019-07-18 09:03:00","2019-07-18 09:04:00","2019-07-18 09:05:00","2019-07-18 09:06:00" ]))

# expected result: pd.DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-18 08:52:00', '2019-07-18 09:00:00', '2019-07-18 09:01:00'])
```

EDIT:
this worked:

```
intersection_X_Y = X.index.intersection(Y.index)  
result  = X.loc[intersection_X_Y].isnull().all(1) & Y.loc[intersection_X_Y].isnull().all(1)
print("result",result [result ].index)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
i_X = X.index[X.join(Y).isna().all(1)]

Out[20]:
DatetimeIndex(['2019-07-18 08:52:00', '2019-07-18 09:00:00',
               '2019-07-18 09:01:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```